# How to improve a question to make it easier to find for future visitors?

Tags: discussion, questions, seo

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335428/version-of-windows-imaging-component) question after searching for hours on problems with [WIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component) after a server migration. The only answer very clearly indicates what the problem was (I moved from a Windows Server 2008 R2 to a Windows Server 2008 SP1 server) and how to fix it.

How do I improve the question/answer to make it more findable for someone in my situation? Are there general principles that could apply to all questions I might find in the future like this?

It would also be nice if the answer there mentioned that you need Windows Server 2008 SP2 installed *before* you can install the platform update.

My original problem:

- Post server migration all my WIC based thumbnail code was crashing
- I knew WIC was supported by Windows Server 2008 server
- I knew WIC was not supported by several earlier OS families

Steps I took:

- Google the actual error codes I was receiving, almost no results
- Step through a debugger to try to isolate the problem
- Reconfirm the code was working on the original server
- Create a test application to confirm it was not an isolated problem
- Finally noticed that the new server was running Windows Server 2008 SP1, not Windows Server 2008 R2. Googled "WIC Windows 2008" on a hunch and found the answer.

Comment: Given your [original version](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/133981/1): are people really referring to Windows 2008 as "2k8"?

Answer (score 1):

That user seems active, you can edit his answer and in the edit summary, just say what you said: "I added additional info to make it more complete or easier to find." The author has the ability to accept or reject your edits, but if you make the reason why you edit it seem positive, they'd be more likely to accept IMO

Comment: The additional information would make the edits go outside the scope of the original question.  It would turn into a question about WIC error codes and required versions instead of Windows Azure.

Comment: It's OK to edit the question in a way that generalizes it - you need to respect the OP, but you don't need to leave his question as it started - especially in a case like this. But make sure the question title is the kind of thing someone searching for the issue would look for...